# Regex: Match 5 or more characters with specified start and end

Tags: regex, matching

I want to find a range of characters with a specified start, end and a minimum length.

For example: From the sequence select a range witch starts with `a` and ends with `c` and contains `5` or more characters.

The sequence: `dabbcbcbabce`

I'm trying to get this result: `abbcbc`

The regex what I'm first tried: `a(.*?)c` and the result of that: `abbc`.

And the second: `a(.*)c` and the result of that: `abbcbcbabc`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew *starts with a and ends with c and contains 5 or more characters* means the count of 5 *includes* the a and c, so `a.{3,}?c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.{3,}?c
```

Literal match `a`, then `3` characters until character `c` found. This gives the total pattern 5 characters - it wasn't clear to me from the question if the start and end should be included in the character count - I have included them.

Similarly, I've not put anything in a capture group - it's known the match will always start with `a` and end with `c`, it's just a matter of deciding if these should be included or not and placing the brackets appropriately.

[Link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4Yl3Ee/1/)

Comment: May require anchoring with `\b` or `^...$`

Comment: OP wrote `contains 5 or more characters` but this will match less than 5 as well.